# Missing references, Nuget and Package-Install don't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution of which the references look like this:

[image]

The [documentation of nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore) says I should use `nuget.exe restore`, which I typed into the package manager console. But I got an error message saying that nuget is not a recognized command.

I have tried these steps:

[Visual Studio/ NuGet missing references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334417/visual-studio-nuget-missing-references)

But no luck. When I open the project in file explorer and go to the bin folder, all dll's are there, so they aren't missing. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the Package Manager Console

`Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine`

This will install the package for the `nuget.exe` you need to your solution packages directory

Then run your desired command (`nuget.exe restore`)